# AVAudioPlayer Crashed On iOS 17, How To Fix?

Tags: ios, crash, avaudioplayer

It worked well on system version before iOS 17. After the iOS system version was upgraded to 17, a large number of crashes occurred. What happened？

```
AQ::API::V2Impl::AllocateBuffer(OpaqueAudioQueue*, void*, unsigned int, AudioStreamPacketDescription*, unsigned int, AudioQueueBuffer**) + 780
1  AudioToolbox                   AQ::API::V2Impl::AllocateBuffer(OpaqueAudioQueue*, void*, unsigned int, AudioStreamPacketDescription*, unsigned int, AudioQueueBuffer**) + 592
2  AVFAudio                       AVAudioPlayerCpp::allocAudioQueue() + 476
3  AVFAudio                       AVAudioPlayerCpp::prepareToPlayQueue() + 32
4  AVFAudio                       AVAudioPlayerCpp::playQueue(AudioTimeStamp const*) + 116
5  AVFAudio                       AVAudioPlayerCpp::DoAction(unsigned int, unsigned long, void const*) + 164
6  AVFAudio                       -[AVAudioPlayer play]
```

Comment: Could you add some code of your app when you instantiate and use the AVAudioPlayer? The stack trace indicates that the play method should be the culprit.